# how to full join 2 dataframes with correct data type?

Tags: r, left-join

```
head(a)
  ID   yr mth
1  1 2021 M04
2  2 2021 M04
3  3 2021 M04
4  4 2021 M04
5  5 2021 M04
6  6 2021 M04

head(b)
    yr mth period_start period_end
1 2015 M03   2015-03-01 2015-03-31
2 2015 M03   2015-03-01 2015-03-31
3 2015 M04   2015-04-01 2015-04-30
4 2015 M04   2015-04-01 2015-04-30
5 2015 M05   2015-05-01 2015-05-30
6 2015 M05   2015-05-01 2015-05-30
```

I want the result is like below, a full join b, and some record in that 2 date fields are missing / in "1900-01-01"

```
  ID   yr mth period_start period_end
1  1 2019 M04   2015-03-01 2015-03-31
2  2 2018 M01   2015-03-01 2015-03-31
3  3 2021 M01   2015-04-01 2015-04-30
4  4 2015 M04         ????       ????
5  5 2021 M03   2015-04-01 2015-04-30   
6  6 2021 M04   2015-04-01 2015-04-30
```

Please advise how to make it. Thanks

Comment: i am expecting something like in SQL 

select a.*, b.period_start, b.period_end from a a left join b b on a.yr = b.yr and a.mth = b.mth; \

Comment: i tried with sqldf in R, but cannot get the date format

Answer (score 0):

Because of reputation I cannot comment with question for clarifications.
However, I would use `dplyr` in r, where we have a "traditional" left join. This will preserve all your rows in the first dataframe (a) and generate missings for the two new columns in (b) where there is no match.
Only the classes of the columns you are merging on need to be the same, the rest can be transformed later one. If the below generates an error, you can share it and we can go from there.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- left_join(a, b, by = c("yr", "mth"))
```

If you want to work on the dates, I recommend the `lubridate` package in r, which makes transforming from and to dates very easy.